# input from terminal list of combinations of dictionaries of lists and lists of dictionaries - from json

Tags: python, json, parsing, input

I want to get from terminal a json that looks like, for example:

```
[{"type":"one", "wrapped":[Slow, Empty, {"type":"two", "called": [Slow,   Error]}]}]
```

It could be any combination of lists and dictionaries, nested in each other. It must be read/converted in a Python list of lists/dictionaries, according to the input.
Is there a way to make this happen?
I have tried several things, but in all of them you have to specify what do you want, either a list, a string, a dictionary but I want any nested combination of them.
Could you help?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--json_input", type=str)

_parse_args() = parser.parse_args()

_args = _parse_args()

argparse_dict = vars(_args)

  #dict type
data = argparse_dict

  #string type
#data = argparse_dict['json_input']

data = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it as a string, then parse as json?

```
import argparse
import json


def read_from_string():
    json_string = '[{"type": "one","wrapped": ["Slow", "Empty", {"type": "two","called": ["Slow", "Error"]}]}]'
    return json_string


def parse_from_args_string():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--json_input", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.json_input


def parse_from_args_file():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--json_file",
                    type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='UTF-8'),
                    required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.json_file.read()


def main():
    json_str = parse_from_args_file()
    json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
    print(json_obj[0]["wrapped"][2])


main()
```

Execute it:

```
python3 a.py --json_file "json1.txt"
```

Output:
`{'type': 'two', 'called': ['Slow', 'Error']}`

Comment: thanks vey much. You answer made me understand that the actual problem is another. 
The input is:
[{"type":"one", "wrapped":[Slow, Empty, {"type":"two", "called": [Slow,   Error]}]}]
Where Slow and Empty, without "", are global dictionary variables.
Do you think it is possible to handle this or it is better that I change my script?

Comment: Without the quotes, its simply an invalid json. So it cannot be parsed with any json library.

Comment: Thank you Anmol. 
I am not trying to write the input in a .json file (from terminal: python script.py --infile input.json). 
I have modified the add_argument to parser.add_argument("--infile",nargs=1, type = argparse.FileType('r')) but still I am not able to read the file - the vars(_args) is: {'infile': [<_io.TextIOWrapper name='input.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>]}.
Do you know how to access the json file?

Comment: Edited the answer to include a working example.

Comment: I think I accepted already the answer, didn't I?
For the upvoting, it says:
"Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."